# Azure Text-To-Speach with stream input and output

Tags: typescript, azure, sdk, text-to-speech

i am trying to create and app where you will write and then hear the transcription. It works but i am sending the whole text and then wait for the whole audio, its possible with the SDK to have an stream input where it can read in realtime my input and send and output as a stream too? so it doesnt have to wait the whole process, it can continuosly send the audio and read the new text.

I know there is a delay between this process but the delay will be really small compared to the time needed to wait for writing the whole text paragraph and wait the whole audio.

```
const textToSpeech = async (text) => {
  // convert callback function to promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let ssml = SSML.replace("__TEXT__", text);

    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key, region);
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = 4; // mp3

    let audioConfig = null;

    // if (filename) {
    let randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 7);
    let filename = `./public/speech-${randomString}.mp3`;
    audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);

    const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
      ssml,
      (result) => {
        synthesizer.close();

        resolve({
          filename: `/speech-${randomString}.mp3`,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        synthesizer.close();
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Currently i am using a file and a text input, but i would like to create a stream conenction alike, so when i start to write it will be continuosly reading and generating a new audio that will be received as a stream too, so i can hear it as it's getting generated and not at the end of the complete generation.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the given **typescript** code snippet and tested it in my environment, I am able to hear the generated audio stream.

**Code:**

```js
const textToSpeech = async (text: string, key: string, region: string) => {
return new Promise<{ filename: string }>((resolve, reject) => {
let ssml = `<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='en-US-Jessa24kRUS'>__TEXT__</voice></speak>`.replace("__TEXT__", text);
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key, region);
speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = sdk.SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Audio16Khz32KBitRateMonoMp3;
let audioConfig: sdk.AudioConfig;
let randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 7);
let filename = `./public/speech-${randomString}.mp3`;
audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);
const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
      ssml,
      (result) => {
        synthesizer.close();

        resolve({
          filename: `/speech-${randomString}.mp3`,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        synthesizer.close();
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
};
const myText = "Hi kamali. How are you?";
const myKey = "key";
const myRegion = "region";
const myFunction = async () => {
const result = await textToSpeech(myText, myKey, myRegion);
  console.log(result);
}
myFunction();
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes this work as an audio file i already have this working. But i want to know if's possible instead of receiving a complete mp3 file (we need to wait the whole file is generated and download) i can hear an live stream while the audio is generated